# c++: Select a subset of a std::vector, based predefined element indices

Tags: c++, performance, vector, sample, subset

I am looking for an efficient way of either trimming or copying a subset of an existing std::vector. The criteria for elements to be eligible for the subset / remain is that their index is contained in a separate predefined std::vector.

```
e.g std::vector<String> Test = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}

std::vector<int> SelectionV = {1,2,5}

Result = {"A", "B", "E"}
```

I will be doing this on a very large vector and probably on a regular basis, so am looking for as efficient method as possible.

An alternative that I am also considering, but again unsure of an efficient method is...

As the object Test is filled (in my case it is 3rd party defined object), it is the result of a single pass through using an iterator (no direct element access is possible). I was wondering if instead it is possible to only add to the Test vector elements that appear in the count defined in SelectionV

e.g

```
int count = 0

for (Iterator.begin, Iterator.end(), Iterator++) {
    if (count is a number contained in selectionV)
        add to Test
}
```

but I assume that will result in a pass through the selectionV on each iteration, which would be far less efficient than simply adding all elements and later selecting a subset.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Does selectionV need to be a vector? Is it static while Test/Result is being filled?

Comment: And how big is SelectionV compared to Test? (Just a few elements? Almost all of them?)

Comment: No selectionV doesn't need to be a vector. Yes Test / Result are static when being filled. SelectionV is likely to be a large percentage of Test, but this is defined at runtime and could be any percentage, although it is definitely going to be a minimum of several 1000 indices.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the standard library:

`std::vector<std::string> Result(SelectionV.size(), 0);`

`std::transform(SelectionV.begin(), SelectionV.end(), Result.begin(), [Test](size_t pos) {return Test[pos];});`

Comment: This is a such a beautiful solution!

Answer (score 1):

You could sort your SelectionV vector by increasing order, and then you could rewrite your for loop something like:

```
int index = 0, nextInSelectionV = 0;
for (Iterator.begin; nextInSelectionV < SelectionV.lengh() && Iterator.end(); Iterator++) {
    if (index == SelectionV[nextInSelectionV]) {
        add to Test
        nextInSelectionV++;
    }
    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- It depends on how large `Test` is and how large `SelectionV` is (as a percentage of `Test`), and whether or not elements in `SelectionV` repeat.  You could potentially optimize by calculating `Not SelectionV` instead.
- Note that in your example, since `SelectionV` is an index, and not a value, lookup is already O(1) fast (that's already a huge plus).
- If `Test` and `SelectionV` do not change, and if they are big, you can also divide up `SelectionV` by **n threads** and have each thread independently lookup values in `Test` and then combine the individual outputs later (not unlike a map-reduce).  The drawback may be a loss in CPU cache hits.
- On repeated calls, you may want to take the difference between your old `SelectionV` and new `SelectionV` and operate on this value.  This type of cache optimization will work well for small number of changes between iterations.

**Most importantly, make sure you really need to optimize this before you spend time to do it (and worse, complicate your code).**

*There is a very high likelihood that other parts of your app (eg I/O) could be magnitudes of times slower.*

Comment: 1) The relative size of the required subset will vary and be decided at runtime.

Comment: 2) Initially what will happen is that the selectionV will remain the same, attempting to select the same subset from a number of different "Test"s.

Comment: @oracle3001 have you actually profiled your samples?  Setting up selectionV and Test (especially if you are reading from disk or a database) could actually take much longer than the selection algorithm.

Comment: The object I am sampling from is a series of Mesh objects (as defined by this library OpenMesh.org). Once loaded into memory, I am attempting to then repeatedly sample a subset of vertices from these objects.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following could be useful for someone in the future:

```
template<typename T>
T vector_select(const std::vector<T>& vector, const std::size_t index)
{
  assert(index < vector.size());  
  return vector[index];
}

template<typename T>
class VectorSelector
{
public:
  VectorSelector(const std::vector<T>& v) : _v(&v) { }
  T operator()(const std::size_t index){ return vector_select(*_v, index); }
private:
  const std::vector<T>* _v;

};

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> vector_select(const std::vector<T>& vector,
                             const std::vector<std::size_t>& index)
{
  assert(*std::max_element(index.begin(), index.end()) < vector.size());
  std::vector<T> out(index.size());
  std::transform(index.begin(), index.end(), out.begin(),
                 VectorSelector<T>(vector));
  return out;
}
```